# How to Access a Function in app_code/vbcode from appcode/cscode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

we have a asp.net Website which is written in c# and vb. I am working with C# in appcode/cscode folder. I need to run a function which is in a appcode/vbcode folder. It 's a .vb file.

Is it possible to call the function from a c# file? If yes, how?

the opposite way is working.

Comment: what's the visibility of the function that you would call?

Comment: Public Class incMail
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: the project where you would call the target function have the visibility to that class?

Comment: no i cant call the function , but the class is public